# NodeJS crypto and binary encoding by default

Tags: node.js, scala, encoding

We have a legacy NodeJS API we are looking to move away from. We are extracting the auth component out of it.

We have a function that hashes a password, that looks a bit like:

```
var sha256 = crypto.createHash('sha256');
sha256.update(password + secret);
return sha256.digest('hex');
```

Aside from the obvious security implications a function like this has, it's encoded using the binary encoding NodeJS has.

If you pass in a String to update, it will use `'binary'` as the encoding format. This results in it actually encoding unicode characters like "`Kiełbasa`" as "`KieBbasa`", before SHA256'ing them.

In our Scala code we are now looking to rewrite this legacy function so we can auth old users. But we cannot find a charset to use on these strings that has the same resulting output. Our Scala code looks like:

```
def encryptPassword(password: String): String = {
  Hashing.sha256().hashString(in, Charsets.UTF_8).toString
}
```

We need the `in` string to be the same as what Node is using, but we can't figure it out.

Ideas? Node.js... not even once.

Comment: Did you implement ```Hashing.sha256()``` on your own or is it part of a library? If there's something like an ```hashBytes(in: Array[Byte])``` method I guess you could do something like ```Hashing.sha256().hashBytes(password.getBytes).toString``` so that you could do a one-to-one port of the original Node.js function. Would that work out for you?

Comment: Hashing is part of Guava. I've tried the code you suggested, but it's no good. The output bytes don't match. They do in cases where there are no unicode characters

Comment: Ok, I tried to experiment a little with encodings and ```ł``` gets translated to ```B``` when forcing its encoding to ```UTF-16LE``` and then back to ```UTF-8```. Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried that. ł does indeed get translated to B. But the rest of the string comes out with extra bytes. The resultant hash becomes different. Good idea though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out this is much easier than it seems. The following code works:

```
def encryptPassword(password: String): String = {
  val in = (password + secret).map(_.toByte.toChar).mkString("")
  Hashing.sha256().hashString(in, Charsets.UTF_8).toString
}
```

Thanks @stefanobaghino